# Hexbin plot with animation

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, plotly

I would like to build an animation for a hex plot with a sliding scale for year, such that it renders a new hex plot for each year.

Currently I am using `ggplot2` and `plotly` [for the animation](https://plot.ly/ggplot2/animations/) and can create this for `geom_point` but it looks like `geom_hex`is not supported by `plotly` and nothing renders in the graph.

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(gapminder)

p1 <- ggplot(gapminder) +
geom_point(aes(y = lifeExp, x = gdpPercap, frame = year))

ggplotly(p1)

p2 <- ggplot(gapminder) +
geom_hex(aes(y = lifeExp, x = gdpPercap, frame = year))

ggplotly(p2)
```

The result I am after would be the equivalent of the graphs produces by `facet_wrap(~year)` but with an animation instead.

```
ggplot(gapminder) +
geom_hex(aes(y = lifeExp, x = gdpPercap)) + facet_grid(~year)
```

I have also looked at [`gganimate`](https://github.com/dgrtwo/gganimate) but had trouble installing would prefer the sliding scale that `plotly` has. Google searches to try and find how to animate a hex plot have been fruitless. Are there any other plotting or animation packages in R I can use to achieve this or a way I can hack `ggplot` and `plotly` to do what I want?

Code on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think a request for: "build me a `plotly` project using `hexbin`" might be over the line of too complex a question for SO. You should break it down into components and show what you have done on each of them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have broken this down in to components as far as my R graphics knowledge and google searching has been able to take me. I know what I want to do, but no idea how to achieve it. But I am happy to be pointed in the right direction :) I am unaware how complex the actual answer to this question might be. In the case of someone having done this or part of this before I have requested code, but I can edit if it detracts from the question. You're a user with high reputation, any suggestions on how I might get started from this? Looks like its Rgraphics 101 for me ;)

Answer (score 1):

The code for ggplotly shows that the dispatch is by way of hte class of the class of the `last_plot()` value:

```
ggplotly
 #---------
function (p = ggplot2::last_plot(), width = NULL, height = NULL, 
    tooltip = "all", dynamicTicks = FALSE, layerData = 1, originalData = TRUE, 
    source = "A", ...) 
{
    UseMethod("ggplotly", p)
}
<bytecode: 0x7feba7ef5ff0>
<environment: namespace:plotly>
```

So as you suspected there appears to be no "trace" to use `plotly` terminology that is associated with an item of class: Class `GeomHex, Geom, gg`. There is, however, a method associated with values of class `GeomPath`, so you can use `geon_density2d` to animate a 2d density with that data. It comes out a bit tangled during the animation, but the overall pattern in the data seems apparent to my eyes:

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(gapminder)

p2 <- ggplot(gapminder) +
geom_density2d(aes(y = lifeExp, x = gdpPercap, frame=year))

ggplotly(p2)
```

There is a warning from ggplot about frame not being used, but keeping the `frame` argument in the `aes(.)` call was necessary to signal `ggploty` that an animation was desired.

Also got bin2d to animate the interval heatmap-type displays:

```
p3 <- ggplot(gapminder) +
geom_bin2d(aes(y = lifeExp, x = gdpPercap, frame=year))

ggplotly(p3)
```